# KnockoutJS - returning a template as a function result

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am using the jQuery UI SelectMenu plugin (https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui) and one of the things it allows is a "format" for the way it renders the list items. Described as follows;

> **format**: null, Accepts a function with a single argument that can be
>   manipulated and returned with any level of manipulation you'd like

So my question is - how could I go about returning a Knockout Template as a function so that I could use the template as the rendering source on this?

Here is a Fiddle that you can toy with, too, but I am also including some of the code

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/w9bsc/)

This is basically what my viewModel looks like;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function User(id, name, points) {
        this.Id = ko.observable(id);
        this.Name = ko.observable(name);
        this.Points = ko.observable(points);
    }

    var viewModel = {
        Users: ko.observableArray([
            new User("users/1", "Stacey", 27),
            new User("users/2", "Ciel", 30)
            ]),
        Selected: ko.observable()
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $template = $('#user-template');

    $('select').selectmenu({
        format: $template
    });
});​
```

And the matching HTML - notice I have a template that I anticipate to bind to a `User`. I am attempting to call upon the template in my JavaScript and pass it as the format parameter - but it obviously doesn't work.

```
<select id="users" 
    data-bind="options: Users, 
    optionsCaption: 'select a user...', 
    optionsText: 'Name', 
    value: Selected, 
    valueUpdate: blur">
</select>
<span data-bind="with: Selected">
    <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: Id"></div>
</span>

<script type="text/html" id="user-template">
    <h1 data-bind="text: Id"></h1>
    <h3 data-bind="text: Name"></h3>
</script>
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the plugin its not very Knockout friendly to work with. You need to create a custom binding. The problem is that the function that you use as format will not receive the actual viewmodel for each option it will receive the option text and the option itself

One hack you can do is to let the option text be the actual object in JSON, then in the format function deserialize to the object and pass that to the render engine, something like

```
function(text, opt){
   var item = ko.mapping.fromJSON(text);
   ko.renderTemplate(rowTemplate, bindingContext.createChildContext(item), **problem here**, "replaceChildren");
}
```

While writing the example I just realized another problem, ko.renderTemplate wants a html element to apply the template to, I do not think it will work with just creating a html element in memory, it has to be attached to the DOM for it to work.

**edit: Here is a way of doing it, just note that its not tester very much so there can be bugs.**

http://jsfiddle.net/w9bsc/42/

```
format = function(text, option) {
    var index = option[0].index;
    if(index == 0 && caption !== undefined) return text;
    if(caption !== undefined) index--;

    var dummy = $("<div />");
    ko.renderTemplate(template, bindingContext.createChildContext(items[index]), null, dummy[0], "replaceChildren");

    return dummy.html();
};
```

Comment: I've actually found it pretty knockout friendly other than the formatting option. Everything else plugs in with ko pretty easily so far.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try and follow this lead and see what it yields. It may not be possible to do what I am trying, but I know I've seen a template passed as a function before.

Comment: Also, I do not necessarily have to have the template rendered. If there is a way to make it render after bindings have been posted. I basically am attempting to return a template as the HTML in the function, and have it render there.

Comment: If you supply me with a jsFiddle with all the CDN stuff linked in I can take a look at it

Comment: There is such a fiddle at the top of the question. All of the CDN stuff is linked in the resources. I had to make a fork of the selectmenu project and publish a github pages ...thing, with a javascript file for the actual plugin in order to make it play nicely with jsFiddle.

Comment: For your convenience, I have pasted all of the cdn links in the first line of the javascript part of the fiddle. You can see it all here : http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/w9bsc/ - the link at the top of the question should still be accurate, too.

Comment: You are amazing ... There still needs to be some work done to it, but this gets me started. Thank you so, so much for all of the hard work and support. I knew this had to be plausible!!!

Answer (score 0):

What about taking a look at the documentation and the demos? It says "Accepts a function". Not a jQuery Object like you did in your code example.

See this line for a valid callback function: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/blob/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/default.html#L58

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the documentation and the demos. In my state of mind last night I could not make much sense of them - however after having the opportunity to sit down today for a bit longer, I understand a bit more what is going on. I stand by my question, though. I wish to find out if it can be accomplished. It looks like the second parameter passed is actually the DOM node (please feel free to correct me if I am wrong), and that might be the hook I need to make it possible.

Comment: Currently, this selectmenu is probably the best one available. I have spent a long time combing the internet for alternatives, and I always wind up coming back to this one - even your older versions were more usable than most of what I find out there, and the fact that it can even accept a function as part of its rendering parameter makes it all the more appealing. I have a lot more faith in the people who make plugins like this, because my knowledge of javascript is limited, and I've seen templating in KO do some very amazing things. I guess what I am saying is - your selectmenu is wonderful.

Comment: Are you aware we are creating a new one, which will hopefully be included in jQuery UI 1.11? Take a look at the jQuery GitHub Account, selectmenu branch!

The format option must be a function and its called on init for every native option. The function passes the option text and the option element itself. You need to return a string (simple text or HTML). Thats all. Does this help? I'm not familiar with knockoutjs.